# jQuery Form won't hide and function return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button

I'm having a problem with one the buttons. It doens't work properly.
When I click "Add Run" button and then "Home" button almost nothing work. The form that is dynamically created doesn't hide and search input doesn't show, and function return undefined.

```
$("#home").on("click", function () {
  $("#search").show();
  $("#addForm").hide();
  $("#noPrevious").hide();
  complete()
  console.log(complete())
});
```

But on the other hand, some things work, they hide or show. For example, after refresh, when I click "All my Runs" it displays text, which will hide after clicking on "Home" button, and on top of that, search input field shows up. I don't understand this. Does anybody know what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Here is CodePen and GitHub. The problem is at the top of .js file.
https://codepen.io/ovy1448/pen/gZrKOX
https://github.com/ovy1448/MyRun/blob/master/js/main.js

Comment: Check the console. You have several errors

Comment: I'm sorry, but where exactly? CodePen and VS Code both return only undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not initializing your values properly. For example, in the case of `bookmarks` your code presumes that `localStorage` has a value with that key. However, that is not necessarily the case. You would need to have a default value for `bookmarks`. A helper `function` could be useful here:

```
function getBookmarks() {
    var bookmarks = localStorage.getItem("bookmarks");
    if (!bookmarks) bookmarks = [];
    return bookmarks;
}
```

and then replace all occurrences of `localStorage.getItem("bookmarks")` to `getBookMarks()` in your code, except the one in the function above. Pay attention to other initializations as well.

EDIT

If you want to parse JSON inside the function, you can do it like so:

```
function getBookmarks() {
    var bookmarks = localStorage.getItem("bookmarks");
    if (!bookmarks) return [];
    return JSON.parse(bookmarks);
}
```

Comment: You're right. I'll go through the code and fix what I can. Thanks for useful advice.

Comment: @LesleyReed you are welcome. You might consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem.

Comment: Hey, so... I'm having a problem with your function. It doesn't work like that. `var bookmarks = localStorage.getItem("bookmarks");` needs to look like `var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));` And then calling the function with `var bookmarks = getBookmarks();` Is it possible that it should be written like I did? Or your function should work?

Comment: @DanielOvári you want write your function at your will, to comply to your needs. However, your suggestion still assumes that localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") will return a sensible value, which is unjustified. If it returns undefined, then JSON.parse will crash. You will need to make sure your function behaves correctly, see my edit.

Comment: Okay, now It works. But it didn't solved my problem, unfortunately. Anyway, thanks Lajos for trying, atleast I've learned something I wasn't aware about.

Comment: @DanielOvári how is it working and not solving the problem? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, basically... The problem is, when I click on "Add Run" and then I click on "Home", the search input doesn't show up. `$("#search").show();` doesn't work. When i refresh and click on "All my Runs" and then on "Home", the search input does show up, it works. But is there is a problem. The function in both cases return undefined. I don't know if that's a scoping problem or what. Still trying to figure it out. The CodePen is updated and you can see in console that your advice working (when you click on "All my Runs"). But unfortunately it doesn't solve my initial problem.

Comment: @DanielOvári your script is too long to analyze, it could take an hour which I unfortunately don't have. Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I can't believe it... It works. Everything. It's done. I tried to chop the code down, just the important stuff left. Then I saw where was the problem. I wrote  `html` instead of `append`, thats why it didn't work properly. Thank you very much. You are my savior. Thank you, thank you. I've learned a lot, must say.

Comment: @DanielOvári I am happy the issue has been resolved.